# Generation of AP not working in Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: wifi, pi-4, access-point, hostapd

I configured the hostapd.conf, dnsmasq.conf and dhcpcd.conf properly. When hostapd launched and querying the status of the services I get:

```
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
```

What could be happening?

Comment: But is it working? If you search for the error msg you will see several situations where this is a warning msg and the AP is fully functional

Comment: No, I cannot even see the SSID to connect with. As well, when launching the hostapd service in debug mode I get this:
nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->1 (UP)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=4 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: TX queue param set: queue=0 aifs=1 cw_min=3 cw_max=7 burst_time=15 --> res=-95
Failed to set TX queue parameters for queue 0.
nl80211: TX queue param set: queue=1 aifs=1 cw_min=7 cw_max=15 burst_time=30 --> res=-95
For queue 0, 1, 2, 3

Comment: Pls add any updates, error msgs to your question. It's impossible to interpret comments like the one above

Comment: The thing is that I had no more space to add the whole command. Anyway, seems that there was an update or something for the packets related with the AP.
It was solved but just:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: `The thing is that I had no more space to add the whole command. ` ???? For future reference: you can edit your question and add loads of text, info, etc etc. Adding these as comments makes esp. terminal output unreadable